# Treating a url object as a literal

Tags: python, python-3.x

I am developing a script for extracting outlook attachments, the code for a specific file is as such:

```
msg = outlook.OpenSharedItem(r'C:\Users\AA\Desktop\November2021\November 01_ 2021.msg')
```

However, I want the script to parse all outlook messages in a folder, and my challenge is how to make the url a literal when it is defined as an object.

```
file_names = glob.glob(os.path.join(source_dir, '*.msg'))

for file in file_names:
        print (file)
        msg=outlook.OpenSharedItem(file)
        for att in msg.Attachments:
                print(att.FileName)
                print(msg.Attachments.Count)
                att.SaveASFile(os.path.join(r'C:\Users\AA\Desktop\MR\Attachments',
                                            str(att.FileName)))
```

When I write the code as such, I get the following error:

```
pywintypes.com_error: (-2147352567, 'Exception occurred.', (4096, 'Microsoft Outlook', "We can't open 'C://Users/AA/Desktop/November2021/November 01...'. It's possible the file is already open, or you don't have permission to open it.\n\nTo check your permissions, right-click the file folder, then click Properties.", None, 0, -2147287038), None)
```

I am assuming this problem is due to the url path not being prefixed by r'[url object]', I don't know how to make a url path object a literal. Would appreciate some help with the matter.

Edit: Changed the word suffix to prefix
Edit 2:
This is the full trace back:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\AA\PycharmProjects\ARCHIVE\Attachment Extractor\main.py", line 23, in <module>
    msg= outlook.OpenSharedItem(file)
  File "<COMObject GetNamespace>", line 2, in OpenSharedItem
pywintypes.com_error: (-2147352567, 'Exception occurred.', (4096, 'Microsoft Outlook', "We can't open 'C://Users/AA/Desktop/November2021/November 01...'. It's possible the file is already open, or you don't have permission to open it.\n\nTo check your permissions, right-click the file folder, then click Properties.", None, 0, -2147287038), None)
```

Edit 3:
Turns out the problem is with the path, it is being saved with "/" instead of " \ ", how do I fix this?

Edit 4:
The following code worked perfectly:

```
import win32com.client
import os

path = r'C:\Users\AA\Desktop\November2021'
files = [f for f in os.listdir(path) if '.msg' in f]
for file in files:
    outlook = win32com.client.Dispatch("Outlook.Application").GetNamespace("MAPI")
    msg = outlook.OpenSharedItem(os.path.join(path, file))
    att=msg.Attachments
    for i in att:
        i.SaveAsFile(os.path.join(r'C:\Users\AA\Desktop\MR\Attachments', i.FileName))
```

However, I don't want the path to be hard coded and have to change it each time manually. I want to use the following code to select the folder:

```
# Identify the source file
root = Tk()
root.withdraw()

root.attributes('-topmost', True)


source_dir = filedialog.askdirectory()

file_names = glob.glob(os.path.join(source_dir, '*.msg'))
for file in file_names:
.
.
.
```

And then carry on from there.

Comment: please paste full(or more) stack trace.

Comment: Does that file actually exist?  The message suggests that a file by that name isn't actually there.

Comment: If these are standard email messages in RFC822 form, you don't need Outlook to extract the attachments.

Comment: The file exists, when I use the single script that identifies the whole file url path prefixed by r ' and close with the apostrophe it works, but when I use the url path as an object, I cannot prefix it with r' which makes the file unreadable. I hope my question is clear enough.

Comment: @ Lei Yang, I have added the full trace.

Comment: You do have a typo in your script; you have `OpenSharedItem(files)` instead of `file`.  Was that a cut-and-paste error, or a real bug?

Comment: A real error, what should it be then? I basically modified the single version code which I copied from another source a long time back.

Comment: Basically as far as I can tell, the problem is the "file" object is not being referenced as a literal, which I am unfamiliar with doing.

Comment: *C://Users/AA/Desktop/November2021/November 01...* does the real error message contain 3 dots `...`?

Comment: Instead of worrying about a problem that's not really a thing (there's no such thing as turning a value into a 'literal', that only means something in context of your source code - there's no point in trying to somehow apply `r'[url object]'` to anything, that's not how that works), how about worrying about what the error message is telling you: the file appears to be open already. Do you have Outlook running when you try this?

Comment: @LeiYang yes the 3 dots are part of the error message.

Comment: @Grismar The file is not open, why does the script function properly when hard referencing the file path, but it doesn't work when I use a loop to get the name of all files in the specific folder that I want.

Comment: can you add a try catch around `OpenSharedItem` so to check every file has such error, or only some files?

Comment: @ahmed, well for one, it's possible "you don't have permission to open it" - try printing the name of each file you're trying to open before opening it, and see if you can open just that file with a script.

Comment: @Grismar please refer to the final edit.

Comment: Well for one, you loop over `file_names` in the first example, as `file` - but you only use `file` to print it. You then proceed to open a file based on `files` - since `files` does not change between iterations, you already have that file open yourself, likely causing the error. You want to be careful telling people to read your code, if you didn't read it carefully yourself.

Comment: That is a typo on my end, apologies for that, it was an iteration I attempted when using `file` didn't work.